# Why tomcat cannot run java mail servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SendEmail</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SendEmail</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SendEmail</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SendEmail</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

SendEmail servlet:

```
// File Name SendEmail.java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail extends HttpServlet{

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "theimmortalbg@gmail.com";

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "web@gmail.com";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "localhost";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));
         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");
         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         String title = "Send Email";
         String res = "Sent message successfully....";
         String docType =
         "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
         "transitional//en\">\n";
         out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
         "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
         "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
         "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
         "<p align=\"center\">" + res + "</p>\n" +
         "</body></html>");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

When I run the servlet with eclipse ee with tomcat server tomcat cannot start.
The reason in my opinion is Mimemessage but why? I know my question mb is stupid but I am new to Java EE and cannot understand please help

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: IV 10, 2014 9:13:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/FirstServlet]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)

Comment: that will be the final result error message - it's Tomcat essentially saying "something went wrong earlier, so I've given up". The underlying error will be somewhere earlier in the start up process, or possibly in a different log file. If you can find a more meaningful stack trace then please include it by _editing_ the original question, as information like that doesn't come across well in comments.

Comment: this is the only log that I have. I know it is broken in this servlet that I posted up. I dont know how to understand where exactly is the problem. I paste this code from tutorialspoint. I have downloaded the javax.mail api from the official page but usually to send mail in my opinion you should have server but here I havent. Also it is possible my ports to be closed. My IP is not real at all on this computer. Everyone can paste the code in eclipse and check. I cannot find more info about the problem but it still exists.